# parse json without explciitely calling the key-name

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, key

I have a json-like file with valid json per line that looks like

```
{"Some_key": {"name": "Tom", "school_code":"5678", "sport": "football", "score":"3.46", "classId": "456"}}
{"Another_one": {"name": "Helen", "school_code":"7657", "sport": ["swimming", "score":"9.8", "classId": "865"}}
{"Yet_another_one_": {"name": "Mikle", "school_code":"7655", "sport": "tennis", "score":"5.7", "classId": "76532"}}
```

So I need to create dictionary(? not really need the dictionary format but anything that could help me associate the key with value, array of two elements for ex) by extracting these first keys (i.e. "Some_Key", "Another_key" etc), that I don't know in advance, and then associating to them the value of score key inside the dictionary. so something like:

```
("Some_key":"3.46", "Another_Key":"9.8", "Yet_another_one_"; "5.7")
```

I don't know the method to extract the content without calling the key-name explicitly, so your ideas are more than welcome !

Comment: Have you already parsed the json?

Comment: Do you want to do a single query into the file or several? In other words, do you want to store the contents of the file in a reusable data-structure held in memory or just perform this one operation on the file?

Comment: @martineau I wanted just to perform this one operation on the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for Python2 and Python3

```
>>> {k: v.get('score') for item in data for k, v in item.items()}
{'Another_one': '9.8', 'Some_key': '3.46', 'Yet_another_one_': '5.7'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the json-like file really has valid json on every line (your example doesn't quite), you could do something like the following (in Python 2 or 3):

```
import json

with open('json-like.txt') as data_file:
    objs = (json.loads(line).popitem() for line in data_file)
    data = {key: value['score'] for key, value in objs}

print(data) # -> {'Yet_another_one_': '5.7', 'Another_one': '9.8', 'Some_key': '3.46'}
```